# angularjs 1 api routing error

Tags: c#, angularjs, api, swagger

I am using angular 1 for this project. and running into 405 (Method Not Allowed) error:

my Api looks like this:

```
[HttpPut]
[Authorize]
[Route("api/License/Update")]
public bool Update(LicenseViewModel licenseViewModel)
{
}
```

This is to update database with model of licenseViewModel
But my routing went to: http://localhost/IRIS.Api6/api/License/Update?id=69499 
awhich gives me error. 405 (Method Not Allowed)

In My service, I have

```
angular.module('portal.core.resources.license')
   .factory('License', ['$resource', 'authSettings', function ($resource, 
   authSettings) {
'use strict';

var License = $resource(
    authSettings.apiServiceBaseUri + 'api/License/:id',
    {
         id: '@licenseSeq'
    },
    {
        update:
        {
            method: 'PUT',
            url: authSettings.apiServiceBaseUri + 'api/License/Update/' 
        },

        licenseTypes: {
            method: 'GET',
            url: authSettings.apiServiceBaseUri + 'api/License/types',
            isArray: true
        },

        licenseStatuses: {
            method: 'GET',
            url: authSettings.apiServiceBaseUri + 'api/License/statuses',
            isArray: true
        },

        funeralServicesAdminFees: {
            method: 'GET',
            url: authSettings.apiServiceBaseUri + 'api/License/:id/FuneralServiceAdminFees',
            isArray: true   
        }
    }
);
```

....

What did I do wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you noticed your update method argument and the argument that you are passing?

Comment: It should supply data as licenseViewModel, instead it mistakenly supplied: params: id:69130, resulting in angula  XHR failed loading: PUT "http://localhost/IRIS.Api6/api/License/Update?id=69130".

Comment: Thanks, Sumit raj,   I noticed data is fetches as  licenseViewModel  from API, after modifying a phone number, it is intended to supply back to update api for updating an database entry. However, it never reached the api because of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used angular but this is how i do in simple javascript

```
 var postData = {
            UserID:@Model.UserID,
            BadgeID: $('#badgeID').val(),
            FirstName: $('#firstName').val(),
            LastName: $('#lastName').val(),
            Email: $('#email').val(),
            MobileNumber: $('#mobNo').intlTelInput("getNumber"),
            LanguagePreferenceID: $('#languagePreferences option:selected').val(),
            FacilityCode: $('#facilities option:selected').val(),
            IsPasswordResetAllowed: $('#passReset').is(':checked') ? true : false,
            ActivityStatus: $('#activityStatus').val()

        };




$.ajax({
                url: '/UserCRUD/UpdateUser',
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(postData),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json"
});
```

This is my controller method signture

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateUser(UserViewModel user)
    {
    }
```

**Conclusion: You need to pass the required LicenseViewModel object.**

Comment: Angular 1 pass data model very differently. It does not not need to assemble the data model again if the data model already exists in the html template.

Comment: In controller, it seems ctrl.license data model is passes this way: ctrl.save = function() {
            License.update(ctrl.license).$promise